# How to reference the initial commit?

Tags: git, git-commit

I've got a script that needs to reference the initial commit in a repository.   git has the special reference `HEAD`, but doesn't have the corresponding `TAIL`.  I cannot find anything in `git help rev-parse` that would seem to help me.

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
git show TAIL
```

Here's one option I have:

```
git show `git log --reverse | if read a commit ; then echo $commit ; fi`
```

That's pretty hacky and depends on the output of git log not changing.

Right now I just tag the initial commit and use that as my refspec.  However, I'd like to release a general tool, so that's not a great option.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Do not use git-log for scripting: use either [`git-rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list), or [`git-log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) with specified custom format (`--format=*<sth>*` option).

There is additional problem with your question: there can exist **more than one** such TAIL root commit (parentless commit) in a repository (even if we discount disconnected branches, such as 'html', 'man' and 'todo' in git.git repository). This is usually result of joining separate projects in one, or using subtree merge of separately developed subproject.

For example git repository has 6 root commits: git-gui, gitk (subtree-merged), gitweb (merged in, no longer developed separately), git mail tools (merged very early in project history), and p4-fast-export (perhaps accidental). That is not counting roots of 'html and 'man' branches, "convenience" branches which contains pre-generated documentation, and 'todo' branch with TODO list and scripts.

---

If you have git 1.7.4.2 or newer, you can use the `--max-parents` option:

```
$ git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD
```

Otherwise, you can get list of all parentless (root) commits accessible from current branch using:

```
$ git rev-list --parents HEAD | egrep "^[a-f0-9]{40}$"
```

Comment: For me, the `git rev-list HEAD | tail -n 1` and `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD` are not returning the same hash value for me. The one using the `--max-parents=0` is in fact getting the initial commit though. Just thought I would point out that the latter seems more reliable.

Comment: @Treebranch this could happen if you have commits with odd timestamps.  adding `--topo-order` to the `rev-list` should fix that, though I think the `--max=parents=0` answer is best.

Answer (score 44):

`git rev-list HEAD | tail -n 1` is a more stable option.

Comment: This would return *one* of tail commits; there can be more than one root (parentless) commit

Comment: This answer worked perfectly and only returned one commit sha whereas `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD` returned 3 commits.

Comment: tail is also not a command that's there by default in windows - works in GitBash on windows though. :)

Answer (score 14):

Not sure what you're trying to do here, but some git commands take `--root` as an option, in order to reference the root of the commit tree, e.g.

```
git rebase --interactive --root main
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the first parent of a merge is the main line of development:

```
git rev-list --reverse --topo-order --first-parent HEAD | sed 1q
```

Comment: If i could award bonus points for using `sed` instead of `head` then I would. `sed 1q` can be pointlessly shortened to `sed q` by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Taken into account there could be multiple initial (orphan) but those commits still reachable from any of the refs it's possible to use:

```
git rev-list --all --max-parents=0
```

or

```
git rev-list --reflog --max-parents=0
```

But if it's required to find root commits including non-reachable ones, `git fsck` could be used:

```
git fsck --root --no-dangling
```

The `--no-dangling` option suppresses warning messages about dangling commits making it easier to process output in scripts.

Answer (score 1):

To get first commit on the repository, run this command:

```
 git rev-list --oneline HEAD | tail -n 1
```