# Reference Git branch start commit

Tags: git, reference, commit

I am trying to find how to reference branch start commit from script. I mean the commit sha at which branch was forked.

Moreover I expect it work for history made from svn repo.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006775/git-how-to-reference-the-initial-commit/1007545#1007545) just gives first commit of repo creation and not feature branch start commit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you're looking for is the command `merge-base`:

```
git merge-base master feature-branch
```

will print the best common ancestor of those two branches, i.e. where they forked apart. (The [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html) has pretty pretty pictures to clarify some of the interesting cases)

An additional tidbit is you can add the `merge-base` flag `--fork-point` to automatically include the name `feature-branch`, read more [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143069/).

Comment: Note that if you've merged between your branch and the trunk at any point, a parent of that merge will be returned rather than the 'original' branch point.  I'm not sure you'll get any better answer, though.

Comment: @Andrew: It depends on the exact use, but generally that's what you want, anyway, not the original one. If you do really want the original one, you can use the `-a/--all` option and take the first one instead of the last one.

Comment: Big help, thanks!  It leads to useful things like `git difftool \`git merge-base master HEAD\``

Comment: Why do you need to specify another branch?? The question was to find the starting commit for the current branch. This can only be 1 commit at the time it was created...