# How to show the first commit by 'git log'?

Tags: git

I have a Git project which has a long history. I want to show the first commit.

How do I do this?

Comment: I only found a way to show the last `git log -1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: how to reference the initial commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006775/git-how-to-reference-the-initial-commit)

Answer (score 418, accepted):

### Short answer

```
git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD
```

<sub>(from [tiho's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188914/how-to-show-first-commit-by-git-log#comment19763574_5189296). As [Chris Johnsen notices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188914/how-to-show-first-commit-by-git-log#comment19774504_5189296), `--max-parents` was introduced after this answer was posted.)</sub>

### Explanation

Technically, there may be more than one root commit. This happens when multiple previously independent histories are merged together. It is common when a project is integrated via a [subtree merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html).

The `git.git` repository has six root commits in its history graph (one each for Linus’s initial commit, *gitk*, some initially separate tools, *git-gui*, *gitweb*, and *git-p4*). In this case, we know that `e83c516` is the one we are probably interested in. It is both the earliest commit and a root commit.

It is not so simple in the general case.

Imagine that *libfoo* has been in development for a while and keeps its history in a Git repository (`libfoo.git`). Independently, the “bar” project has also been under development (in `bar.git`), but not for as long *libfoo* (the commit with the earliest date in `libfoo.git` has a date that precedes the commit with the earliest date in `bar.git`). At some point the developers of “bar” decide to incorporate *libfoo* into their project by using a subtree merge. Prior to this merge it might have been trivial to determine the “first” commit in `bar.git` (there was probably only one root commit). After the merge, however, there are multiple root commits and the earliest root commit actually comes from the history of *libfoo*, not “bar”.

You can find all the root commits of the history DAG like this:

```
git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD
```

For the record, if `--max-parents` weren't available, this does also work:

```
git rev-list --parents HEAD | egrep "^[a-f0-9]{40}$"
```

If you have useful tags in place, then `git name-rev` might give you a quick overview of the history:

```
git rev-list --parents HEAD | egrep "^[a-f0-9]{40}$" | git name-rev --stdin
```

### Bonus

Use this often? Hard to remember? Add a git alias for quick access

```
git config --global alias.first "rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD"
```

Now you can simply do

```
git first
```

Comment: I believe ``git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD`` will do the same, and is a bit simpler.

Comment: @tiho: Yes, it does the same, and is simpler; though that option had not quite been [“invented”](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=ad5aeeded3295589b2573b143f754762a56f8f82) at the time of this question/answer.

Comment: It occurs to me that first commit is more of a _leaf_ commit than a _root_ commit

Comment: @tiho I think your answer should be its own answer and not just a comment. That way it will be more prominent and you will get much-deserved points.

Comment: @RussellSilva I do not care about points, but I believe it is possible to edit other people's answers, which would probably be better than adding a new one. I'm not really comfortable doing it myself though, feel free to do it :)

Comment: One more addition, if there was no checkout, then the `HEAD` does not exist. But if there is was a fetch, then you have to use `FETCH_HEAD` may be with the path to the branch at the end of the `log` command.

Comment: Why have you answered a question asking specifically how to do this using git log with an answer using git rev-list?   Has something been lost in edits to the question over the years?

Comment: Thanks! I've made a `first` alias with `!git log $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)`

Answer (score 662):

I found that:

```
git log --reverse
```

shows commits from start.

Comment: interestingly `git log --reverse -5` makes it ignore the `--reverse` for some reason

Comment: @Dan2552 Looks like a bug, should be reported?

Comment: looks like it first limits the results to 5 entries, and then reverse

Comment: @太極者無極而生 is right, that is the documented behavior.

Comment: this prints all the commits accessible from `HEAD` in reverse order, the accepted answer is more sophisticated

Comment: git log --reverse | head -6

Answer (score 62):

You can just reverse your log and just head it for the first result.

```
git log --pretty=oneline --reverse | head -1
```

Comment: `git log --reverse` reverses the history, so you have to use `head -1` instead of `tail -1` to get the first commit.

Comment: it'd be best if git didn't not ignore the `-n` flag when `--reverse` is given.

Comment: `--pretty=oneline` is not actually pretty, use `--oneline` instead to avoid printing out the entire SH1 checksum.

Answer (score 29):

To see **just the commit hash of the first commit:**

```
git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD
```

To see **the full `git log`, with commit message, for just the first commit:**

```sh
git log $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)
```

To see **all `git log` messages in reverse order**, from the first commit at the top (instead of at the bottom) to the last (most-recent) commit at the bottom (instead of at the top):

```sh
git log --reverse
```

### References:

1. How I learned the first command above: [the accepted answer] [How to show first commit by 'git log'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188914/how-to-show-first-commit-by-git-log/5189296#5189296) (the 2nd command above was my own contribution)
2. I learned about `git log --reverse` [from the most-upvoted answer, by @Nyambaa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5188990/4561887)

Answer (score 17):

```
git log $(git log --pretty=format:%H|tail -1)
```

Comment: or `git log $(git log --reverse --pretty=format:%H|head -1)`

Comment: help for me. real "first commit"

Answer (score 5):

Not the most beautiful way of doing it I guess:

```
git log --pretty=oneline | wc -l
```

This gives you a number then

```
git log HEAD~<The number minus one>
```

Comment: Fails when there are merge commits (as a result of branching): `% git log HEAD~63
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~63': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Answer (score 2):

`git log --format="%h" | tail -1` gives you the commit hash (ie `0dd89fb`), which you can feed into other commands, by doing something like

`` git diff `git log --format="%h" --after="1 day"| tail -1`..HEAD `` to view all the commits in the last day.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the same result as the accepted answer with less typing:

```bash
$ git fsck  --root
root 3fa77c58f85c591f9c6a1b0510228e4aec704697
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
```

This works because the first commit of most git repos is the root node.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get first commit with date, committer name and commit message, you will run this command.

```
git log master --pretty="%t %aD %aN %s"| tail -1
```

`t`tree hash , `ad` refer to author name, `aN` refers to author name and `s` for subject.

If you want to get first commit with branch that make from master branch(copy from master), you will refer to master and other branch.

```
git log master...docs --pretty="%t %aD %aN %s"| tail -1
```