# How to log first 10 commits in Git

Tags: git, logging, git-log

Two questions:

1. How to show the first 10 commit in git from beginning to end. (no branch)
2. How the specify the commit index and log it. (show the second or third)

I know that git use parent to link the commit, it's easy to log the commit from end to start.
like: `git log HEAD~10`

But i need to query from the start to end, is it possible?

Comment: Related: [How to show first commit by 'git log'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188914/how-to-show-first-commit-by-git-log)

Comment: scroll to @kostix answer

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Simply log everything with one line format and tail the output:

```
git log  --pretty=oneline | tail -n 10
```

Comment: Great! That's what am looking for. Tks @CharlesB.

Comment: Or, use `git rev-list HEAD | tail -n 10` to get the 10 IDs to list, which you can then show in whatever format you like (not limited to the one-line method).

Comment: `tail` seems to lose the nice coloring that I get in my git console. Passing a parameter like `git log --oneline -10` as in the other answer works as I expected.

Comment: This is clearly the hard-core Unix way, lol. Please see @kostix answer.

Comment: The downside of this method is that i can only see my pushed commits.

Comment: `git log  --pretty=oneline -10` will show with colors

Comment: git log --oneline -1

Answer (score 353):

```
git log -10
```

Would show 10 latest commits matching the revision spec (a missing spec means "all commits").

See manpage:

```
git help log
```

section **`Commit Limiting`**

```
-<number>, -n <number>, --max-count=<number>
    Limit the number of commits to output.
```

Comment: simple, and doesn't depend on `tail` being available on your platform.

Comment: & doesn't mess with git formatting/coloring. This should be the accepted answer x100

Comment: Not what the op wanted: he wanted the `first` 10, not the `latest`.

Comment: @Timo, quite possibly yes, but the question as stated is open for interpretation, and a lot of peple seem to end up upvoting my answer just because of these open differences. So while I technically agree with you, let's keep it as is, I suppose ;-) Among the technically correct suggestions, I like the most the torek's comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: @kostix "How to show the first 10 commit in git from beginning to end" isn't "open to interpretation" as far as I'm concerned. It's obviously asking for the *first* 10 commits, not the *latest*.

Comment: @BobbyJack, the number of upvotes disproves your point. I mean, I tried to explain that this is a social issue. You did not get it. Fine, let's get over it.

Comment: @kostix I accept that many people have interpreted the question incorrectly — only the OP can explain what they actually meant, of course! However, I think it's very clear when they say " it's easy to log the commit from end to start — git log HEAD~10 — but i need to query from the start to end" that they want the oldest 10 commits, not the newest.

Answer (score 43):

Here my approach,

To get first 10 commits:

```
git log -n 10
```

-n is number

**Additional**
To get next 10 commit skip first 10 :

```
git log --skip=10 -n 10
```

Comment: I think this should be the acceppted answer. Using tail will cause --graph to stop working in git log

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. works like a charm for me

Comment: you lose the font color on the console using tail as well.
this is the right answer

Answer (score 20):

i would use below simple syntax command;

```
git log -10 --oneline
```

Comment: Think this is the most efficient way!

Comment: Hm, but this prints 10 last **not** first commits.

Answer (score 18):

To get the last 10 commits:

```
git log HEAD~10..HEAD
```

To get them in oldest-to-newest order:

```
git log --reverse HEAD~10..HEAD
```

Note that if there are merges, this may show more than 10 commits; add `--first-parent` if you only want to traverse through the first parent of each branch.

For far more detail, see the documentation for `git rev-list`.

---

Edit: You've already gotten a useful answer above to "show commits near the start of history" (again, see the caveats about multiple non-connected commit DAGs in a repo).  But you can also do, e.g.:

```
git log --no-walk `git rev-list HEAD | tail -n 10`
```

and:

```
git log --no-walk `git rev-list --reverse HEAD | head -n 10`
```

depending on which order you want the results.

Comment: Tks for your reply. But i don't need the last 10 commits but the first.
To be specific, if the commit is A-B-C-D-E-F-G(HEAD).
How to log the A-B-C and how to log C by the index 2?

Comment: Oh!  There's no guarantee that there is a single "first commit", but if there is, see the link @CharlesB added.

Comment: The way can be work. any natural way?
git log --pretty=oneline | wc -l
git log HEAD~<The number minus one or index>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I needed to avoid '-10' style options in my git aliases. that accept number arguments.

Answer (score 18):

the best result comes with combination of both best answers:

```
git log --pretty=oneline -10
```

Comment: Thanks I use this as a [git alias](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Git/aliases) to quickly display the recent commits without filling my terminal. I called the alias `lkj =  log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit -10`. Now I realize it doesn't answer the OP's question but I came here looking for the simple number switch.

Answer (score 5):

Simply log everything reverse -1 means list one log

```
git log  --reverse -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Because... more detail :p

1. How to show the first 10 commit in git from beginning to end. (no
   branch)
2. How the specify the commit index and log it. (show the
   second or third)

---

By (no branch), you might be asking about the `reflog` rather than any given ancestry chain.  The following has nothing to do with the branch you are on.

`git log -g --pretty=oneline | tail -10`

```
<sha> HEAD@{###}: action: summary (old)
<sha> HEAD@{###}: action: summary (older)
...
<sha> HEAD@{###}: action: summary (oldest)
```

- `-g` is `--walk-reflogs` Instead of walking the commit ancestry chain, walk reflog entries.q
- add `|cut -d ' ' -f 2|tr -d ':' > log` to log only the reflog commit index.

---

The following will show the earliest ancestors of the currently checked out branch.

`git log --reverse --pretty=oneline | head -10 | cat -n`

```
1 <sha> summary (oldest)
2 <sha> summary (second)
```

- `--reverse`  Output the commits in reverse order.
- Can't use simply `-n 10` or `-10` since it breaks `--reverse`
- `cat -n` adds line numbers (commit index?)

---

Answer (score 2):

Try this neat output format:

```
git log --date=short -10 --pretty="%C(Yellow)%h %x09 %C(reset)%ad %x09 %C(Cyan)%an: %C(reset)%s"
```

It will print short lines with colors, like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants more than just git one-line log:

```sh
git log --reverse | awk 'NR>1 {print last} {last=$0}; /^commit/ && ++c==11{exit}'
```

where the `11` at the end should be set to `1` more than the number of commits you want.

As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23142313/642311) points out `git log --reverse -n 10` doesn't work as you need it to. (*I suppose it would need to be non-commutative to give you the ability to chose the first 10 commits in reverse order or the last 10 commits* )