# how to get git project information

Tags: git

We have server, which is used for creating all project by git.
There are several project say project1.git ,project2.git and prohectx.git
How may i know who has created project1.git and statistics of project?

Comment: What sort of information/statistics are you looking for?

Comment: like who has created, when has been created. Since it is on remote machine and i don't have access to that machine. right now. Does git command can provide this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creation of the project is the first commit, and it has author and date attached to it. To display use:

```
$ cd project1.git
$ git log --reverse --pretty=medium | head -3
commit 3fdc617258b295f3fc1cdd6d6d7f9d98bd294513
Author: John Doe <john@microsoft.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 6 11:34:35 2012 +0200
```

This assumes the git history has only one root (see  [How to show first commit by 'git log'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5188914/11343) for discussion about it)

Comment: yes that right, But still we can't say who has run `git init` or `git --bare init` means who has initiated git repository

Comment: You have to look at who created the folder, only the file system or the OS can give you the info

Answer (score 4):

However, you can also use **git log** to look for specific commits.

git log --stat show different stat of changes introduced at each commit

for more details you can refer [Git Reference](http://gitref.org/inspect/)

Answer (score 3):

for a status:

```
git status
```

to get a history of commits issued to the git repo:

```
git log
```

ps: make sure you clone a project to your local computer (since it's a project that exists on a remote machine)

Comment: I am repeating my self, what i said in last comment: like who has created, when has been created. Since it is on remote machine and i don't have access to that machine. right now. Does git command can provide this information?

Comment: for finding the initalizer of the project, find out who the first one to commit a file to the project. you can figure this out usign github's network graph.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just look at the project's first commit? That's usually indicative of who created the repo and when:

```
git log --reverse
```

will show commits in reverse, so the root commit will be first.