# How do I cryptographically sign all commits on a branch?

Tags: git, pgp, git-filter-branch

I have PGP key that let's me sign the commits via `git commit -S`. To sign my last commit I did a `git commit -S --amend --no-edit` and it signed my commit.

Now, I want to sign all the commits that are there in the branch `filtered`.

I tried: `git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git commit -S --amend --no-edit'`

and it gives me an error message:

```
$ git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git commit --amend --no-edit -S' HEAD
Rewrite 07b0ac12f5fe1d8963d7ae0ac7fbda50cb6e74a9 (1/10)gpg: skipped "Anubhav Saini <IAmAnubhavSaini@users.noreply.github.com>": secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
could not write rewritten commit
```

Another issue: raising another `git commit --amend --no-edit -S` results in:

```
(filter-test)$ git commit -S --no-edit --amend

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Anubhav Saini <iamanubhavsaini@gmail.com>"

[filter-test c5ea180] Removing defer and async from scripts
 4 files changed, 28 insertions(+), 28 deletions(-)
```

### Questions

1. How to batch sign the commit messages?
2. What is raising another sign doing actually and behind the scene?

Answer (score 3):

Consider that rewriting history to sign all the commits in a branch may be overkill.

Because of the git object model, a commit exists in context. Signing the head commit alone also imputes your blessing to its immediate parent (or parents if it is a merge commit) as well as their parents in turn all the way back to day one of your repository.

This is why signing a tag for an official release, for example, is sufficient. Git objects are immutable because each one’s SHA-1 object name is derived from its content. Therefore, starting from a known trusted point allows you and others to chase pointers (which is what `git log`, `git checkout`, `git fsck`, and so on do behind the scenes) to verify integrity.

If you are working on unpublished history, consider condensing the history with `git merge --squash` or `git rebase -i` and signing the resulting commit.

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup of your repository before you get started:

```
tar czf my-repo-backup-2022-03-04.tar.gz ./my-repo
```

Sign all commits in since first commit without modifying commit date:

```
FIRST_COMMIT="$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)"
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' "${FIRST_COMMIT}"..HEAD
```

With help from [GuyPaddock here](https://superuser.com/a/1368424/730855) and [Chris Johnsen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5189296/712334).

Answer (score 0):

probably you should setup a [gpg-agent](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html) with a decent timeout for passphrase validity (enough to run the whole sequence of rewrites). See this Arch [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#gpg-agent) for help. Thus, can enter the passphrase once, before the rewrite, and then all invocation of gpg will use that unlocked key for a while.