# How to remove backups made by git filter-branch

Tags: git

I wanted to fix the Name and Email on my commits so I ran

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "<OLD NAME>" ];
then
    GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="<NEW NAME>";
    GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="<NEW EMAIL>";
fi
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "<OLD NAME>" ];
then
    GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="<NEW NAME>";
    GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="<NEW EMAIL>";
fi
' -- --all
```

And

```
git filter-branch -f --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' -- --all
```

But this leaves backups and I am having difficulty removing them.

Any idea how I can get rid of them?

Comment: @TonyArra I actually tested that and it didn't work I could try it few more times but not sure if it would change anything

Comment: If that's the case, please upate your question with debugging details (what did you try; what error messages did you see; etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better option, considering [`git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309) are obsolete after Git 2.22 or more, is to use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (python-based, to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md)):

```
git filter-repo --path your/big/file --invert-path
```

Or:

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
```

Its man page mentions, about `git filter-branch`:

> Despite the use of `--all` and `--tag-name-filter`, and filter-branch's manpage claiming that a clone is enough to get rid of old objects, the extra steps to delete the other tags and do another `gc` are still required to clean out the old objects and avoid mixing new and old history before pushing somewhere.

`git filter-repo` will [force you to make a backup first](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnewren%2Fgit-filter-repo%2Fblob%2Fdocs%2Fhtml%2Fgit-filter-repo.html=#FRESHCLONE=), then proceed to change the history of the local repository you are filtering.

---

Note that you still need `git filter-repo` to *sign* commit though, as explained in [`newren/git-filter-repo` discussions 209](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/discussions/209#discussioncomment-474986).

See [How do I cryptographically sign all commits on a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71350955/6309).

Or, as suggested by the [OP POQDavid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2478571/poqdavid) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71982211/how-to-remove-backups-made-by-git-filter-branch/71983072?noredirect=1#comment127196827_71983072):

```
git rebase --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit -n -S' -i
```

Or, using the `rebase --root` option [I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309391/6309):

```
git rebase -i --root --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit -n -S
```

Comment: Do you happen to know an alternative for `git filter-branch -f --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' -- --all` but with git filter-repo?

Comment: @POQDavid No but you don't need it to fix commit name/email: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58263677/6309 and https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnewren%2Fgit-filter-repo%2Fblob%2Fdocs%2Fhtml%2Fgit-filter-repo.html=#_user_and_email_based_filtering=

Comment: Yes I wanted that to sign all the commits again

Comment: @POQDavid Exactly. One `git filter-repo` command ought to be enough for that, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58263677/6309.

Comment: so that would keep the commits signed?

Comment: @POQDavid not with filter-repo indeed (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/discussions/209#discussioncomment-474986). For signing, you [still need `filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71350955/6309).

Comment: i sort of managed to do it with `git rebase --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit -n -S' -i`

Comment: @POQDavid That would work too. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I just noticed that leaves the first commit this `git rebase -i --root --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit -n -S'` just does all the commits

Comment: @POQDavid True. I have edited the answer accordingly, and included the link to the `rebase --root` option.