# Make Git repo public without revealing past commits

Tags: git, github

I have a private repo that had a bunch of sensitive data committed.  However, I recently cleaned up all of the sensitive data so that it can be public.  If I change a private repo on GitHub to become public, are all past commits visible (i.e. could someone see that sensitive data from the past)?

If so, how do I make the repo public without making the past commit history public?

Comment: Was anyone else using the repo, or was it just you?  If only you, you could rebase/squash all the commits into one commit, and then force push the change to the origin repo, and then make it public.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: `git checkout --orphan public_master master` is one of the methods to squash all the commits on master into the index, after which run `git commit` to commit it as the new root of `public_master`. And then you could push `public_master` as you like.

Comment: @mparnisari because I was first asking the OP whether or not anyone else was using the repo.  The answer only makes sense when no-one else has been using the repo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to desired commit:

```
git checkout <your_commit_hash>
```

Go down to the initial commit leaving all current changes:

```
git reset <intial_commit_hash_here> --soft
```

Then commit with amend option

```
git commit --amend -m"My new initial commit"
```

And then you are ready to push to your public repo

```
git push <your_remote> master
```

---

P.S.
The original change history will still be available with `git reflog` but will not be pushed to remote repo

---

UPD.
To get the id of the first commit use the command from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5189296/3344612):

```
git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD
```

Comment: I followed your procedure and I am now in a new origin that only has one commit. If I `git pull origin master` I get an error message (`failed to push some refs to "github.com/,foo" updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes`

Comment: @pietro you are on a dangerous ground here. What you are trying to do is erasing the whole history from the original repository. If you **really** want to do this and you know exactly what you are doing then use `--force` flag when pushing.

Comment: I know that's what I was afraid of! not sure what I have done wrong. I didn't checkout the committ because I was already there (it was my last commit) is that it?

Comment: This is my history:    
 1975  git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD
 1976  git log
 1977  git reset 7142a466feea856d02de1c37abfbceb086e4db83 --soft
 1978  git commit --amend -m "Public commit" 
 1979  git push

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend cloning (or just copying all the non .git files) from the current repo into a new repo and then pushing the new repo out as public.

Comment: Still not sure if it makes the past commits visible, but this is what I ended up doing.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Alex Beals, Commit history is stored in .git folder. Since, you don't copy that Folder, You can safely follow the Answer.