# How to return first commit in case of no existing tag?

Tags: git

This is how I am searching for the commit of the latest tag:

```
tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
base=$(git rev-parse $tag)
```

But if there is no tag existing, it should return the first commit of the repo.

```
first=$(git log --reverse --oneline)
```

How do I get only the first commit - not a list, like with the command above?
And how do I do an `or` for the base? If tag existing, return its commit, if not, return first commit.

Comment: `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188914/how-to-show-first-commit-by-git-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a test.

The `git tag` command does not *document* an exit status.  Hand-testing it shows that it *has* one, but you may not wish to depend on this undocumented feature.  To avoid depending on the exit status, we can check the output instead:

```
tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
if [ "x$tag" = x ]; then
    # there is no tag
    # so here we'll do something different
fi
```

In modern shells you don't need the slightly silly `"x$tag"` trick:

```
tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
if [ "$tag" = "" ]; then ...; fi
```

for instance.

To get the hash ID of the root commit reachable from the current commit, use `--max-parents=0`.  Ideally there's only one such root, but it's possible, depending on the shape of the repository history, to have more than one, in which case you must decide what you want to do about this.  One way to sidestep that possibility is to decide in advance that you want whichever root is found by traversing only first-parents.

Rather than `git log`, which requires adding `--pretty=format` or `--format` directives to extract just the hash ID, it's usually more sensible to use `git rev-list` here.  The minor annoyance with the rev-list "plumbing" command is that you *must* supply a starting point, whereas `git log` will assume `HEAD` if you don't supply a starting point.  This *is* minor because it's trivial to write in `HEAD`:

```
first=$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 --first-parent HEAD)
```

Putting these together we get:

```
tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
if [ "$tag" = "" ]; then
    tag=$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 --first-parent HEAD)
fi
```

or the more compact form:

```
tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
[ "$tag" != "" ] || tag=$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 --first-parent HEAD)
```

Actually *trying* this we find that `git describe` in a repository where the `git describe` step fails and outputs the empty string does this:

```
$ git describe --tags --abbrev=0
fatal: No tags can describe '2808ac68000c62c3db379d73e3b7df292e333a57'.
Try --always, or create some tags.
$ echo $?
128
```

So the "test" can just be: *did `git describe` succeed?*  In this case we get:

```
tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 ||
    git rev-list --max-parents=0 --first-parent HEAD)
```

When run in my example repository I get:

```
$ tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 ||
>         git rev-list --max-parents=0 --first-parent HEAD)
fatal: No tags can describe '2808ac68000c62c3db379d73e3b7df292e333a57'.
Try --always, or create some tags.
$ echo $tag
460cce09ff42c43a6826af9deaab0f7a8d1f6f44
```

To make the error message vanish, we can redirect it to `/dev/null`:

```
tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 2> /dev/null ||
    git rev-list --max-parents=0 --first-parent HEAD)
```

Note that if you want to hide the error message, you have to do this redirection, no matter which of the testing methods you pick.

Comment: Wow, great answer. Thank you for that. In my case I'm using busybox, which is in some parts limited (compared to bash). But it should work with busybox as well, right?

Comment: Maybe I got something wrong, but the `or` has to be for the `base` variable. If there is a tag, it has to be handled with `$(git rev-parse $tag)` and this commit sha should be the result. If it is not existing, then the first commit sha should be returned.

Comment: I was assuming that you wanted either the rev of the lowest-but-closest tag, or the rev of the root commit (which you might feed to `git format-patch` for instance), but if you need something else, it should be easy to construct given my answer. Just split off whichever parts you want into whichever variables you want.

Comment: Note that if you do get a tag hash ID and want a *commit* hash ID, you'll want to run `git rev-parse $tag^{commit}`. Given a commit hash ID, if you want a commit hash ID, and feed that commit hash ID to `git rev-parse $hash^{commit}`, you'll get the commit hash ID back. So you can also do the above and then just run `git rev-parse` on it as appropriate.

Comment: The first commit doesn't have a tag mandatory. Does this matter for your solution?

Comment: No. (Try it out.)