# Make the current commit the only (initial) commit in a Git repository?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I  currently have a local Git repository, which I push to a Github repository.

The local repository has ~10 commits, and the Github repository is a synchronised duplicate of this.

What I'd like to do is remove ALL the version history from the local Git repository, so the current contents of the repository appear as the only commit (and therefore older versions of files within the repository are not stored).

I'd then like to push these changes to Github.

I have investigated Git rebase, but this appears to be more suited to removing specific versions.
Another potential solution is to delete the local repo, and create a new one - though this would probably create a lot of work!

ETA: There are specific directories / files that are untracked - if possible I would like to maintain the untracking of these files.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435646/how-do-i-combine-the-first-two-commits-of-a-git-repository ("How do I combine the first two commits of a Git repository?")

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I combine the first two commits of a Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/435646/456814).

Comment: and this: [How to squash all git commits into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657017/how-to-squash-all-git-commits-into-one)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66091688/8079868

Answer (score 1139, accepted):

Here's the brute-force approach. It also removes the configuration of the repository.

**Note**: This does NOT work if the repository has submodules! If you are using submodules, you should use e.g. [interactive rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase-i)

Step 1: remove all history (**Make sure you have a backup, this cannot be reverted**)

```
cat .git/config  # save your <github-uri> somewhere
rm -rf .git
```

Step 2: reconstruct the Git repo with only the current content

Before step 2 if you have not set up `init.defaultBranch` configuration then, please do it via `git config --global init.defaultBranch <branch-name>` you may choose `main` as `<branch-name>` in the current example

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Step 3: push to GitHub.

```
git remote add origin <github-uri>
git push -u --force origin main
```

Comment: Thanks larsmans - I have opted to use this as my solution. Though initialising the Git repo loses record of untracked files in the old repo, this is probably a simpler solution for my problem.

Comment: @kaese: I think your `.gitignore` should handle those, right?

Comment: Save your .git/config before, and restore it after.

Comment: @lalebarde If you restore .git/config after `git commit -m "Initial commit"` then you can probably skip the `git remote add ...` part, assuming that was already in your config, and move straight on to pushing. It worked for me.

Comment: Deleting the `.git` folder may cause problems in your git repository. If you want to delete all your commit history but keep the code in its current state, it is very safe to do it as in the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26000395/2019689

Comment: Be careful with this if you are trying to remove sensitive data: the presence of only a single commit in the newly pushed master branch is **misleading - the history will still exist** it just won't be accessible from that branch. If you have tags, for example, which point to older commits, these commits will be accessible. In fact, for anyone with a bit of git foo, I'm sure that after this git push, they will still be able to recover all history from the GitHub repository - and if you have other branches or tags, then they don't even need much git foo.

Comment: So many bad answers in the world and after an hour I finally got this to do my bidding!

Comment: push to GitLab - error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246503/how-to-fix-you-are-not-allowed-to-push-code-to-protected-branches-on-this-proje/32267118

Comment: @RobertMuil is it safe now? Could you edit it if not?

Comment: @beppe9000 I don't know for sure, but I don't think it is: the wiki hasn't changed since I made my previous comment. I won't edit because I don't know an easy solution apart from completely deleting *all repos*...

Comment: Does this send only the modified portions of the repository? e.g. if I have a large file F already in the top commit and do this, will the forced push send F's contents again over the wire?

Comment: Above still not removed all history what I had to change was one extra command at the end: 

git push origin --mirror

Comment: So this answer is not a real solution?

Comment: Using @Zeelot's answer below was the easiest and least destructive way to purge the history. It should be the selected answer

Comment: why not use `mv .git .git-old` which would be safer, then remove .git-old when finished? Also, you can initially run `git ls-files > files.txt` and then add them back with a simple `cat files.txt | awk '{print "git add " $0 }' | sh`

Comment: Hi, related to this full history rewrite, is there some ways to actually forbid this as part of repositories permissions in bitbucket cloud ?

Comment: please make sure to fire this command before git init ```git config --global init.defaultBranch main```

Answer (score 846):

The only solution that works for me (and keeps submodules working) is

```
git checkout --orphan newBranch
git add -A  # Add all files and commit them
git commit
git branch -D master  # Deletes the master branch
git branch -m master  # Rename the current branch to master
git push -f origin master  # Force push master branch to github
git gc --aggressive --prune=all     # remove the old files
```

Deleting `.git/` always causes huge issues when I have submodules.
Using `git rebase --root` would somehow cause conflicts for me (and take long since I had a lot of history).

Comment: this should be the correct answer! just add a `git push -f origin master` as the last op and sun will shine again on your fresh repo! :)

Comment: This solutions works locally. What if I have a remote master? Will have side effects ?

Comment: Does this not keep old commits around?

Comment: @JonePolvora  
git fetch; 
git reset --hard origin/master http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785107/git-pull-from-remote-can-i-force-it-to-overwrite-rather-than-report-conflicts

Comment: after doing this, will the repo free space?

Comment: @Brad: I was wondering the same thing. Seems that --orphan only gets the last commit so that the remaining ones are thrown away when the branch is deleted. Reference: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: Good for times when you're not using Github

Comment: This doesn't work with a remote repo? I've used the script, but with no success. My .git folder is still huge. I've also tried scripts by @gru and echo. Any advice?

Comment: The cleanest way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Tried the accepted answer exactly as it is written and it didn't work. Tried this answer exactly as it is written, worked like a charm. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Git will keep the old files around for a while, to get rid of them run `git gc --aggressive --prune=all`.  In addition, git will continue to store history for any commits that are referenced with branches or tags.  To check, run `git tag -l` and `git branch -v`, then delete any you find.  Also double check your remote with `git ls-remote`, you may need to delete remote tags/branches as well or when you fetch you will get all the linked files again.

Comment: I believe you should add @JasonGoemaat 's suggestion as the last line to your answer. Without `git gc --aggressive --prune all` the whole point of losing history would be missed.

Comment: Instead of deleting original _master_ branch, one can rename it `git branch -m master old_master` and set push mode to current-branch-only `git config --local push.default current`. This way one can keep historical commits in separate branch and work in sync with repo in the fresh master.

Comment: This does not work. I do get this error: git branch -M master -f
error: refname refs/heads/newBranch not found

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Deleting .git and similar stuff is unsafe since it does not guarantee the same tree state after recommiting the files.

Comment: Important note for thos working with GitLab, BitBucket, etc... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029867

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you! Worth mentioning that when I did it on a protected master branch I got a "pre hook declined error" I had to unprotect the branch and retry. Worked like a charm.

Comment: This was the only working solution in my case! Thanks!

Comment: This does the job but wouldn't free disk space until issuing `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=all --all` followed by the mentioned git gc (it might do that some time later automatically, dunno)

Answer (score 127):

This is my favoured approach:

```
git branch new_branch_name $(echo "commit message" | git commit-tree HEAD^{tree})
```

This will create a new branch with one commit that adds everything in HEAD. It doesn't alter anything else, so it's completely safe.

Comment: Best approach! Clear, and do the work. Additionally, i rename the branch with a lot of changes from "master" to "local-work" and "new_branch_name" to "master". In master, do following:
    git -m local-changes
    git branch -m local-changes
    git checkout new_branch_name
    git branch -m master<

Comment: This looks really short and sleek, the only thing I don't understand or haven't seen yet is HEAD^{tree}, could somebody explain? Apart from that I'd read this as "create new branch from given commit, created by creating a new commit-object with given commit-message from ___"

Comment: The definitive place to look for answers to questions about git reference syntax is in the `git-rev-parse` docs. What's happening here is `git-commit-tree` requires a reference to a tree (a snapshot of the repo), but `HEAD` is a revision. To find the tree associated with a commit we use the `<rev>^{<type>}` form.

Comment: Nice answer. Works well. Finally say `git push --force <remote> new_branch_name:<remote-branch>`

Comment: And everything in one line:

`git branch newbranch $(echo "commit message" | git commit-tree HEAD^{tree}) | git push --force origin newbranch:master`

Comment: if one wants to overtakte the commit message of the last commit, use `git branch newbranch $(git log -1 --pretty=%B | git commit-tree HEAD^{tree}) | git push --force github newbranch:master`

Answer (score 36):

The other option, which could turn out to be a lot of work if you have a lot of commits, is an interactive rebase (assuming your git version is >=1.7.12):`git rebase --root -i`

When presented with a list of commits in your editor:

- Change "pick" to "reword" for the first commit
- Change "pick" to "fixup" every other commit

Save and close. Git will start rebasing.

At the end you would have a new root commit that is a combination of all the ones that came after it.

The advantage is that you don't have to delete your repository and if you have second thoughts you always have a fallback.

If you really do want to nuke your history, reset master to this commit and delete all other branches.

Comment: After rebase completed, I can not push: `error: failed to push some refs to `

Comment: @Begueradj if you've already pushed the branch you rebased, then you will need to force push `git push --force-with-lease`. force-with-lease is used because it is less destructive than --force.

Answer (score 21):

Variant of *larsmans*'s proposed method:

Save your untrackfiles list:

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard > /tmp/my_untracked_files
```

Save your git configuration:

```
mv .git/config /tmp/
```

Then perform larsmans's first steps:

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
```

Restore your config:

```
mv /tmp/config .git/
```

Untrack you untracked files:

```
cat /tmp/my_untracked_files | xargs -0 git rm --cached
```

Then commit:

```
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

And finally push to your repository:

```
git push -u --force origin master
```

Answer (score 8):

Below is a script adapted from @Zeelot 's answer. It should remove the history from all branches, not just the master branch:

```
for BR in $(git branch); do   
  git checkout $BR
  git checkout --orphan ${BR}_temp
  git commit -m "Initial commit"
  git branch -D $BR
  git branch -m $BR
done;
git gc --aggressive --prune=all
```

It worked for my purposes (I am not using submodules).

Comment: I think you forgot to force push master to complete the procedure.

Comment: I had to make a slight modification. `git branch` will include an asterisk next to your checked out branch, which will then be globbed, causing it to resolve to all files or folders as if those were branch names too. Instead, I used `git branch --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)"` which gave me just the branch names.

Comment: @not2qubit: Thanks for this. What would be the exact command? `git push --force origin master`, or `git push --force-with-lease`? Apparently the latter is safer (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509543/how-do-i-properly-force-a-git-push)

Comment: @BenRichards. Interesting. I'll try this again at some point with a folder that matches a branch name to test it, then update the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This deletes the history on the `master` branch (you might want to make a backup before running the commands):

```
git branch tmp_branch $(echo "commit message" | git commit-tree HEAD^{tree})
git checkout tmp_branch
git branch -D master
git branch -m master
git push -f --set-upstream origin master
```

This is based on the answer from @dan_waterworth.

Answer (score 5):

You could use shallow [clones](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) (git > 1.9):

```
git clone --depth depth remote-url
```

Further reading: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/05/handle-big-repositories-git/

Comment: Such clone can not be pushed to a new repository.

Comment: It would be useful to know how to circumvent that limitation. Can someone explain why this can't be force pushed?

Comment: The answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900103/why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone

Answer (score 5):

Just delete the Github repo and create a new one. By far the fastest, easiest and safest approach. After all, what do you have to gain carrying out all those commands in the accepted solution when all you want is the master branch with a single commit?

Comment: One of the main points is to be able to see where it was forked from.

Comment: I just did this and it is fine

Answer (score 4):

`git filter-branch` is the major-surgery tool.

```
git filter-branch --parent-filter true -- @^!
```

`--parent-filter` gets the parents on stdin and should print the rewritten parents on stdout; unix `true` exits successfully and prints nothing, so: no parents.  `@^!` is [Git shorthand for](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) "the head commit but not any of its parents".  Then delete all the other refs and push at leisure.

Answer (score 4):

> What I'd like to do is remove ALL the version history from the local Git repository, so the current contents of the repository appear as the only commit (and therefore older versions of files within the repository are not stored).

A more conceptual answer:

git automatically garbage collects old commits if no tags/branches/refs point to them. So you simply have to remove all tags/branches and create a new orphan commit, associated with any branch - by convention you would let the branch `master` point to that commit.

The old, unreachable commits will then never again be seen by anyone unless they go digging with low-level git commands. If that is enough for you, I would just stop there and let the automatic GC do it's job whenever it wishes to. If you want to get rid of them right away, you can use `git gc` (possibly with `--aggressive --prune=all`). For the remote git repository, there's no way for you to force that though, unless you have shell access to their file system.

Comment: Nice addition, when seen in context of @Zeelot 's answer.

Comment: Yup, Zeelot's has the commands which basically do this (just differently, by starting completely over, which might just be fine for OP). @MogensTrasherDK

Answer (score 4):

All the answers are awesome but I would like to put another approach with simple commands

```
git clone --depth 1 <remote-url> .
git commit --amend -m <commit message you want>
git push --force
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps to clear out the history of a Github repository

First, remove the history from .git

```
rm -rf .git
```

Now, recreate the git repos from the current content only

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Push to the Github remote repos ensuring you overwrite history

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<YOUR ACCOUNT>/<YOUR REPOS>.git
git push -u --force origin master
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from the `community wiki` answer, or otherwise add value?

Answer (score 2):

The method below is exactly reproducible, so there's no need to run clone again if both sides were consistent, just run the script on the other side too.

```
git log -n1 --format=%H >.git/info/grafts
git filter-branch -f
rm .git/info/grafts
```

If you then want to clean it up, try this script:

http://sam.nipl.net/b/git-gc-all-ferocious

I wrote a script which "kills history" for each branch in the repository:

http://sam.nipl.net/b/git-kill-history

see also: http://sam.nipl.net/b/confirm

Comment: Thanks for this. Just FYI: your script to kill the history for each branch could use some updating - it gives the following errors: `git-hash: not found` and `Support for <GIT_DIR>/info/grafts is deprecated`

Comment: @ShafiqueJamal, thanks, the little "git-hash" script is `git log HEAD~${1:-0} -n1 --format=%H`, here, http://sam.aiki.info/b/git-hash
It would be better to put it all in one script for public consumption. If I ever use it again, I might figure out how to do it with the new feature that replaces "grafts".

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# By Zibri (2019)
#
# Usage: gitclean username password giturl
#
gitclean () 
{ 
    odir=$PWD;
    if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
        echo "Usage: gitclean username password giturl";
        return 1;
    fi;
    temp=$(mktemp -d 2>/dev/null /dev/shm/git.XXX || mktemp -d 2>/dev/null /tmp/git.XXX);
    cd "$temp";
    url=$(echo "$3" |sed -e "s/[^/]*\/\/\([^@]*@\)\?\.*/\1/");
    git clone "https://$1:$2@$url" && { 
        cd *;
        for BR in "$(git branch|tr " " "\n"|grep -v '*')";
        do
            echo working on branch $BR;
            git checkout $BR;
            git checkout --orphan $(basename "$temp"|tr -d .);
            git add -A;
            git commit -m "Initial Commit" && { 
                git branch -D $BR;
                git branch -m $BR;
                git push -f origin $BR;
                git gc --aggressive --prune=all
            };
        done
    };
    cd $odir;
    rm -rf "$temp"
}
```

Also hosted here: https://gist.github.com/Zibri/76614988478a076bbe105545a16ee743

Comment: Gah! Dont make me provide my unhidden, unprotected password at the command line! Also, the output of git branch is typically poorly suited for scripting. You may want to look at the plumbing tools.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
pip install commitcleaner
cd {your project}
commitcleaner
```

This command will remove commit history of a current branch. I referenced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26000395/10386667) of similar thread and then created a pip installable [python project](https://github.com/developer0hye/commitcleaner) for easy usage.

Answer (score -1):

I solved a similar issue by just deleting the `.git` folder from my project and reintegrating with version control through IntelliJ. 
Note: The `.git` folder is hidden. You can view it in the terminal with `ls -a` , and then remove it using `rm -rf .git` .

Comment: thats what he's doing in step 1: rm -rf .git ?

Answer (score -1):

For that use Shallow Clone command 
git clone --depth 1 URL - It will clones only the current HEAD of the repository

Answer (score -3):

> To remove the last commit from git, you can simply run

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

> If you are removing multiple commits from the top, you can run

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

> to remove the last two commits. You
>   can increase the number to remove even more commits.

[More info here.](http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html)

[Git tutoturial here](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) provides help on how to purge repository:

> you want to remove the file from history and add it to the .gitignore
>   to ensure it is not accidentally re-committed. For our examples, we're
>   going to remove Rakefile from the GitHub gem repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/defunkt/github-gem.git

cd github-gem

git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

> Now that we've erased the file from history, let's ensure that we
>   don't accidentally commit it again.

```
echo "Rakefile" >> .gitignore

git add .gitignore

git commit -m "Add Rakefile to .gitignore"
```

> If you're happy with the state of the repository, you need to
>   force-push the changes to overwrite the remote repository.

```
git push origin master --force
```

Comment: Remove files or commits from the repository has absolutely no relation with the question (which asks to remove history, a completely different thing). The OP wants a clean history but wants to preserve current state of the repository.

Comment: this does not produce the result asked in the question. you are discarding all changes after the commit you keep last and losing all changes since then, but the question asks to keep current files and drop history.