# Can I clone from remote repository, but treat my local version as if it was created using 'git init'?

Tags: git, repository, git-clone

I would like to 'git clone' from a remote repository with boilerplate code, but treat it as new repository created via 'git init', meaning I don't want it to have remote/origin and any commit history.

Basically what I want to achieve is in effect similar to doing:

```
git clone [remote_url]
rm -r .git
git init
```

But I am wondering if there is a *git way* to do it.

Comment: This seems an esoteric thing to want, so I imagine there's not a built-in way to do it.  What's the use-case here?

Comment: I think your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683279/make-the-current-commit-the-only-initial-commit-in-a-git-repository

Comment: Oli Charlesworth: I have a repository with code that I usually use for  new applications, but I want to treat every new app as new. Perhaps this is achieved in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest that I can imagine to what you want is to do a shallow clone, and then remove the remote manually.

```
git clone --depth 1 [remote_url]
git remote rm origin
```

If you then check `git log`, you'll see only one commit.

The last commit message will remain; if you want to remove it do `git commit --amend`.