# Share git repository without history so it can be merged back again

Tags: git, git-merge, pull-request

I have a private repository that has old credentials and other private information in the git history. I am contracting with an outside party to do some work on the codebase, but I do not want them to have access to the history.

I know that I can give them a copy of the repository without the `.git/` folder, but I also want to make it as easy as possible for them to use `git` while they work, and be able to merge their branch back into my master branch when they are done.

I was thinking of just making a clone with `--depth 1`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30001366/2903532) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37499365/2903532), and sending them a tarball of that local clone. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you consider cleaning up the history of the repo so that the files are never there? `git filter-branch` could help if history is long.

Comment: Or BFG repo cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if you want to share your initial history :
  have a look at `git filter-branch` to remove (or edit) the files you don't want to share, then share this version of your repo
- if you have no need to shareyour old history :
  you can also start a new repo, with the "current tarball" as a first commit, and work on that repo together with the other team ; on your local computer, you can still access your "old" history by stitching it together with your new repo's history.
  See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42457384/86072) to see how to create a new repo, which still keeps the history of an older repo