# Duplicate a git repository without history

Tags: git, version-control

I want to copy a git repository to another location so I can start working on a different project using that same code base. Is it enough to simply clone the repository and delete the `.git` folder and run `git init` or do I have to do some additional work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clone git repository without history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001304/clone-git-repository-without-history)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy a git repo without history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368837/copy-a-git-repo-without-history)

Comment: Not if you have sub-repositories or use git LFS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to keep the working directory but delete all the git history, tags, branches, etc. you can just delete the `.git` directory and run `git init .`.

You may want to check also the local `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files if they exist, so that they conform to the new project needs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, deleting `.git` and `git init` will work. Also use 
`git clone --depth 1` 
so you won't be downloading history, which you going to delete.