# How to make my git repo smaller

Tags: git, version-control, scalability

I've got a git repo that I make automated commits to every day multiple times a day, but now the git repository is getting huge and taking a while to clone onto other devices.  I'm wondering what the easiest way would be to slim down my repository.  Is there a way to remove older commits to slim down my repository size?

Comment: Without knowing more about *what* you're committing it's going to be hard to figure out the real cause here.

Comment: Is it ok for your team to remove the older commits (that means the older versions won't be found/tracked)? Or are you just want to remove useless files from order commits?

Comment: No, I want to remove older commits.  Basically, I have a git repo that has a list of suricata rules that have been changing daily.  Every time a change is made a new commit is created, so there are a ton of commits, I really don't think we'd every have a reason to need a commit more than a week old.

Comment: @MikeSchem Have you pushed all the commits to remote repo? And What's branches do you want to remove the old commits, only for master branch or other branches?

Comment: I have pushed the commits to a remote repo.  I only want to remove from master.

Comment: @MikeSchem I added an answer to keep the commits in last one week, you can have a try. For other branches if you want to delete the commits older than one week, you can use the similar commands.

Comment: @MikeSchem Can you clean the older commits now?

Comment: If the size of the main repository isn't that important, but the cloning time is, look into [Shallow clones](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), specifying `--depth X` to say "X number of commits back from the tip of the branch". Also, are you sure you want to use a git repository at all? A database might be better suited for your needs.

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size<br>
I have some similar problem and it has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the commits older than one week on master branch, you can use below steps:

1. Get the commits for the last one week which you need to keep by the command

   ```
   git log --oneline --since="one week ago" master
   ```

   Then you will get the commits in last one week as below (latest commit on top, older commit in bottom):

   ```
   d1fc497 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) message5
   ac89b87 message4
   8c3e839 message3
   d4ffc42 message2
   3f1d63a message1
   ```

   The first/older commit `3f1d63a` need to used in below steps.
2. Checkout an orphan branch from the first commit you want to keep (as the commit `3f1d63a` in above example):

   ```
   git checkout --orphan temp 3f1d63a
   git commit -m 'init commit'
   ```
3. Rebase the last one week commits based on the `temp` branch, and force push `master` branch:

   ```
   git rebase --onto temp 3f1d63a master
   git push -f origin master
   ```

Now `master` branch will only contains the commits for the last one week.

---

To remove the useless objects in your local git repo, you can use below commands:

```
rm -Rf .git/refs/original
rm -Rf .git/logs/
git gc
git prune --expire now
```

Now your local repo's size should be smaller.

Comment: This didn't seem to work.  I did all the steps except I didn't push to the git. When I checked the directory size it was still the same size.

Comment: The reason why your local repo still in the same size is caused the useless objects are not cleaned. And I added the commands to prune your local repo size in the end of my answer, you can have a try.

Comment: Did you execute `git push -f origin master` command firstly? If you are not execute the command firstly, all the useless refs and objects can not be deleted since the tracking branch `origin/master` still point to them. And after force push to remote `master` branch, you can also clone the remote repo to another directory and double check the repo's size.

Comment: Did you try the commands after force push? And what's the result?

Answer (score 1):

git provided `git gc` command and `git repack` to improve the maintaining an old and fat repository. Also there is some un-written rules which could help to prevent the current repository grow fast(i.e using `lfs` for large files and so on).

Use [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/maintaining-a-git-repository-321848291.html) for more detail.

Comment: This is a good solution for making one git repo smaller, but I want to actually remove older commits. Also, this only decreased my repo size from 470 MB to 405

Comment: @MikeSchem I think the title is not very clear. Also, thanks to share your result of using those methods :). Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683279/make-the-current-commit-the-only-initial-commit-in-a-git-repository)? I think some of answers may help you. Hope it helps.