# How to reset / clean a GitLab repository

Tags: gitlab

I want to reset one of my repositories on gitlab, but without deleting the whole project.

I've read on Gitlab Forums (on the post https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-can-i-delete-a-repository-and-push-a-new-one/690) two different options:

First: Deleting the physical repository from disk. I've tried renaming the folder (repo.git) but then, gitlab gives me a 404 error trying to access to it.

Second: Deleting all branches. This solution do not work too, because, I cannot delete the main branch (on my case master), and when I create a new one, the new branch requires to specify a "original" branch. I cannot create a clean branch without any data and change the main to it.

Someone know how to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: "reset one of my repositories on gitlab, but without deleting the whole project" What does that mean?

Comment: I'm talking about cleaning the git repository only, without affect issues / comments / code snippets etc

Comment: So couldn't you just delete all the files, turn that into a commit, and push it? Or do you mean you wish to delete the whole _history_? If the latter, this is well discussed already, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683279/make-the-current-commit-the-only-initial-commit-in-a-git-repository

Answer (score 9):

Delete all branches except `master`, unprotect `master` in `settings -> repository -> protected branches` and execute:

`git push -f master origin` .

Comment: That doesn't work:

$ git push -f master origin .
fatal: invalid refspec '.'

Comment: make commits else you will get an error

Answer (score 6):

I've been asking myself this same question, and running through the same issues you mentioned. I have repositories with a lot of crud in them that shouldn't have been there before which is why I wanted to do this. I can easily reduce my local repo to < 1MB and force push that to gitlab, however the hosted repo simply doesn't reduce in size (I presume artefacts remain in the repo). Moving all issues across to a new repo isn't an option either as the dates all get "today's" date and is cumbersome.

I think I've discovered a way though. First export your current repo and download the tar.gz file from gitlab (this contains the repo, issues etc). Then create / modify / whatever the new repo you wish to replace the existing one with. Once ready, create a bundle of that new repo, ie: the one you want (from within that repo):

`git bundle create /tmp/project.bundle --all`

Then replace the `project.bundle` in the downloaded tar.gz with the new `project.bundle`.

Now you can create a new project on gitlab by importing that tar.gz, and you should hopefully have all your issues, tags, etc from the original, but with the new repository.

Now you can rename your old and new repos and hopefully you should be good to go. It's not ideal I know, but in my case it was the issue history I wanted to keep, and a pruned version of the repo.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround, and it worked for me.

- At first, on project's settings/repository page **change the default branch to a non-master** branch,
- Then **delete the master** branch and **push the new files to master**.
- At last **change the default branch back to master** and **delete all the other branches** you don't want.

Answer (score 4):

Full 2023 solution to only reset the repository to a new/ clean state:

1. In your repository, navigate to `Code -> Branches` and delete all branches except for `master`/ `main`
2. In your repository settings, navigate to `Repository -> Protected branches` and toggle `Allowed to force push` for the master/ main branch to `ON`
3. Locally, create a new and empty directory, and initialize a new repository: `git init -b master` or `git init -b main`
4. Create some file (or your initial commit files) and add them: `git add --all`
5. Create the initial commit: `git commit -m 'Initial commit after reset'`
6. In your repository, navigate to `Code -> Repository` and copy the SSH url (use the clone button, including the username)
7. Add the remote in the newly-created directory: `git remote add origin <URL_FROM_PREVIOUS_STEP>`
8. Force-push to upstream: `git push -f --set-upstream origin master` or `git push -f --set-upstream origin main`
9. In your repository settings, navigate to `Repository -> Protected branches` and toggle `Allowed to force push` for the master/ main branch to `OFF`

> PS: also consider running `Run Housekeeping` and `Prune unreachable objects` from `Settings -> General -> Advanced` to reduce the size of your repository after cleanup :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the branch's history, Matt already suggested the same strategy I have done.
The only think to say is to "unprotect" a protected branch, otherwise you may face with an error like this:

```
git push -f origin last_known_good_commit:branch_name
```

> remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.

Go to your project "repository settings/protected branches" and unprotect it. After you make the update operation you can protect your branch again.
Be careful to rewrite the repository history if you are working with other people on the same project.