# How to remove a specific commit from GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

There are two rhel servers. One is GitLab (**server A**) and another server (**server B**) is where I want to run `git clone` command to checkout remote repo and run all `git add/commit/push` commands. It was working just fine until I accidentally pushed a large `jar` file into the remote repo under **master** branch. There are no developers except myself to use.

I see the commit I made with the large jar file and I want to physically remove it from **GitLab** but so far I failed it.

From reading stackoverflow, I was able to revert back to previous commit in the server B but GitLab still retains the commit with large file.

Then I blew away existing copy of local repo from the **server B** then ran `git clone` then I  ran into this problem.

```
git clone git@<server A>:example/someproject.git
Cloning into 'someproject'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 187, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (187/187), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (115/115), done.
remote: fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 535136313 bytes)
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the re                                                                                    mote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I have a feeling that commit one before last in where large jar file is pushed causing this chaos.

I researched each fatal error but I couldn't connect dots to either how to delete the problematic commit from GitLab nor checkout remote repo to the server B.

At this point, I'd like take any advice/thought on this matter. Just for note, if I tried to view that problematic commit, I get 503 error. For other commits (simple text change), I can view them just fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53772415/how-to-reset-clean-a-gitlab-repository thread found a solution for me.