# Number of commits double after fetching from force pushed repo

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I found out that there was some secret info committed early in my git repository. Although
it could've been found a long time ago, I still wanted to remove it, so I made a new clone
and then ran

```bash
git-filter-repo --path file1.txt --path file2.txt --invert-paths --replace-text replacements.txt --force
```

After making a backup of the remote repository, I force pushed by doing

```bash
git remote add origin https://github.com/...
git push origin --force --all
```

Finally, I ran `git fetch` in my original local repository (that has changes) which succeeds.

My issue is with the output of `git rev-list --count --all`  before and after fetching:

- Before filtering, it's 1478.
- After filtering, it's 1475.
- After fetching the force pushed repository, it's 2531.

Why were the number of commits almost doubled after fetching? I'm worried that the old commits may be still in the repository. If they are, how can I get rid of them?

`git stash` followed by `git rebase -i origin/main` (where I `drop`ed the 4 commits that were listed) lowered it to 2493, but I'm still not sure why it's still so much higher. `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` didn't changed the count.

Comment: "I'm worried that the old commits may be still in the repository." That's certainly to be expected. Commits are not magically destroyed. However, the commits that you don't want anyone to see should be unreachable at this point. If not, there was something wrong with how you did the filter-repo. "If they are, how can I get rid of them?" That depends on where the remote is kept. But you didn't tell us that.

Comment: @matt I'm a bit confused. If commits can't be destroyed, then what's the point of filtering? Likewise, if the commits are unreachable, then why not destroy them? Either way, `git fsck --lost-found --unreachable | wc -l` outputs 438, which doesn't account for all of the commits. Also, the remote  is on GitHub, as shown in the `git remote add origin https://github.com/...` from the post.

Comment: For GitHub, read https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#. They are quite clear about this. You can change history, but you should consider the secret info to be now 100% public.

Comment: And I would turn your question around: if commits could be readily deleted, what would be the point of Git as a history keeper?

Comment: If you run `git log --graph --oneline --all`, do you see commits which you intended to delete ? If yes, it means some references ( branches ? remote branches ? tags?) still point at these

Comment: The surest way to really get rid of those commits is to delete the remote repo altogether and create a brand new one in its place. If you're using GitHub, any old PR is a reference to its head, and that will keep the history you don't want as well.

Comment: Commits only actually go away when there are no references to them at all, and that state can be quite difficult to achieve with anything short of a fresh repo.

Comment: I wrote up an answer to a similar question before https://stackoverflow.com/a/56876518/3216427

Comment: Try a fresh clone and see what the commit count is. If it's the smaller number that you expect, then you know your filtering worked. But the larger number will still be present on all existing clones, until the newly unreferenced commits are garbage collected, and you have no control over when that occurs on other people's local copies. For most people they will be gc'd at the default settings, but there's no guarantee of that. Some people (and tools) turn gc off completely, for various reasons. (For example AzDO and GH might never garbage collect.)

Comment: @TTT A fresh clone gives the expected number (1475). Assuming no one creates references to the unreferenced commits, they won't get pushed to the remote, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. However, anyone that has already been using the repo for anything, would already have references to those old commits. If this is a public repo you should assume the secret info is compromised, just in case.

Comment: Try a fresh mirror clone, though. A regular clone won't get the PR references from GitHub, but a mirror will.