# Pushing single clean commit/branch to remote

Tags: git, push, branch, git-remote

I have a repository "A" with tons of history, several branches, etc. I want to take a single, clean, working commit and use it as the starting place for a new remote "B", such that there will only be one commit visible on remote "B," and from there I can ideally push to "B" and "A," or even better have that branch of "B" track the origin "A"

Comment: You might be better off cloning repo A, removing the local `.git` folder, starting a new repo using `git init`, and pushing that to remote B. Using the git tools for this might be cumbersome, especially considering it sounds like you don't want repo A's history.

Comment: `as the starting place for a new remote "B"` - Did you mean `new repository "B"` instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make the current commit the only (initial) commit in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683279/make-the-current-commit-the-only-initial-commit-in-a-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+make+the+current+commit+the+only

Answer (score 1):

Check out the commit where the code is in the state you want it, and create an *orphan* branch, which will result in a parentless commit when you commit it:

```
git checkout --orphan clean-branch
git commit -a
git push B clean-branch
```

Then, checkout the regular branch again and keep working there. Whenever you want to synchronize again, do:

```
git reset --soft clean-branch
git commit
git push B clean-branch
```

A soft reset keeps your work directory, but makes it so that the next commits will be on the specified branch.

(I make no statement about whether this workflow is a good idea.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you create a new branch off branch “master” you inherit its commit history. The exception is an `orphan` (or disconnected) branch. An orphan branch doesn‘t have a parent-child relationship to the master branches’ commits.
Most commits have one parent commit, one obvious exception being root commits which have no parent commits. Creating an `orphan branch` will retain the working tree of the branch it’s based on, but without an ancestor commit.

# create new branch **b** and switch to that: `git checkout --orphan b`

# create a **README.md** file: `touch README.md;`

# add the README.md file to git: `git add README.md;`

# make **first commit** to this branch: `git commit -m 'orphan branch initial commit';`

# push branch **b** and set upstream branch to branch **a**: `git push --set-upstream a b;`

---

Upstream branches define the branch tracked on the remote repository by your local remote branch (also called the remote tracking branch). To check the tracking branches by writing `git branch -vv`