# Folder didn't push to GitHub, showing as an icon only

Tags: git, github

I was trying to add my `OnlineStore` folder to `GitHub` which has two main folders inside it. A `ServerApp` and a `ClientApp`.
Not sure what I have done wrong that ClientApp folder looks like this and I can't even click on it to go inside.

This is also the actual link to it:  https://github.com/BlakeAghili/OnlineStore

How can I fix this now?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

You just get this “right arrow in a folder” icon in GitHub because you happen to commit the `./ClientApp` directory although **it was itself a Git repository** (i.e., containing a `./ClientApp/.git` directory, which means that a shell command such as `cd ClientApp && git status` would work).

As a result, the `ClientApp` sub-directory is seen by Git/GitHub as a so-called [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), as shown by the following URL and screenshot:

> https://github.com/BlakeAghili/OnlineStore/commit/ff0e522#diff-6ee288c5ef71eb1fd24077fc2aadab3d

[image: GitHub Submodule]

#### What to do now?

You might not want to keep this git-submodule in your history, and commit its contents instead? In this case, you could either:

- follow this SO answer: [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/9164010)
  (note that the procedure is a bit tricky, as usual when it comes to using submodules; and you should probably do a backup of all your project code beforehand, just in case);
- or more simply and also more aggressively, restart your main project history, doing something like this SO answer: [Make the current commit the only (initial) commit in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9683337/9164010),
  maybe **after moving away** (not deleting) the history of your `ClientApp` folder that you might want to keep as well − `mv ClientApp/.git ../ClientApp.backup.git`