# How can I reset everything from git project and push as one commit

Tags: git, github

How can I delete all my commits without erasing the documents and push it as one commit?

Comment: do you mean [git squash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9683279/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+delete+all+commits

Answer (score 3):

There are several options, one of them is :

```
git reset --soft <sha1 of first commit in your repo>
git commit --amend
```

Answer (score 0):

@LeGEC's answer is probably the 'right' way to do it, but another option is to simply delete your `.git` folder and re-run `git init`, which will totally reinitialise your repository. You can then `git add -A` and `git commit -m <message>`, but you'll need to `git remote add <remote-name> <remote-link>` again before you `git push <remote-name> <branch-name>`. This also assumes you weren't doing much with branching. If you simply had one default branch `master`, then all's well, but e.g. if you'd renamed it (say, to `main`), then you'll need to do that again before pushing. If you had more complex branching, then this is probably not the best approach, unless you also want to reset that.