Copy files but none of git history?
Suppose you have two git repositories, oldPackage and newPackage.
oldPackage has a lot of history and newPackage is empty.
oldPackage performs a service for one geographical market and newPackage will perform a similar service for a different geographical market.
oldPackage should start as a template/baseline for newPackage.
But ultimately, both must maintain their own independent histories.
It's time prohibitive to manually copy and paste contents of oldPackage into newPackage. However, I'm concerned that git clone could introduce a spaghetti problem where extricating one from the other is a continual problem.
How might I copy the contents of one package over excluding any git history?
Is it as simple as cp -r oldPackage newPackage --exclude .gitignore?

The git history and stuffs are located under .git folder. So excluding it will only keep your files.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9683337/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+all+history

You have few options:

Clone the repo, delete .git and re init
git clone ... xxx
cd xxx
rm -rf .git
git init


You have a clean repo with the latest filesystem


Add multiple remotes to your "new" repo and use git cherry-pick to get the desired commit/branch
Full answer here:
git - apply a commit on another branch to the working copy

Use git archive to create zip of your content and then use it as your base template.


P.S.
There are more options.... i recommend adding multiple remotes and use cherry-pick.
It will allow you later on to grab more commits between the repositories, for example if you fixed a bug, or if you added content which you need on both of them etc.
As mentioned above:
git - apply a commit on another branch to the working copy

When you clone old to create an (initial state) of new, the new project will contain the files of old and the history to that point.
It may help to remember that git is a distributed system; the only relationship between the repository containing old and the repository containing new is whatever relationship you choose to configure.
By default when you clone old into new, old is setup as a remote of new so that any changes made in new can be pushed back to old.  There is nothing sacred about that relationship; it is established merely as a convenience.
But you can simply remove the remote configuration and treat new as a completely stand-alone repository.  If you do that, then new will retain the history of old to the point it was cloned to form the baseline for new.
Or, you can keep the remote and never push any changes.
This might be useful if the changes you will make in new are relatively minor, and it would be helpful to be able to pull any updates (bug fixes, etc) that may be later applied in old.  This might enable you to rebase your new code onto the fixed/updated old code.  If old and new are expected to diverge significantly, or if you are not familiar with rebasing, then you probably don't need to worry about this.
If you don't want or need to keep the old history in the new repo, after cloning, simply cd into the new repo and rm —rf .git. This will remove the existing git repository that was cloned, leaving a folder that simply contains the files of old. You can then git init to initialise a new, empty repository and git add . and git commit to create a history-free initial commit for new.
