How Can I Remove All History (commits and etc.) of Huge GIT Repo
I have a git repo over 200GB in size. How can I completely delete the history of this repo? I don't want to move it to a new repo due to the size of the repo.
I only want to remove all commit history of this repo. Without moving to a new repo or creating a new one or pushing all the files again.

Just delete the .git folder? I assume you do have a bare repo hosted somewhere in case you need to reclone it some day, though.

I want to remove all history from GIT server.

Let's ask differently: what do you want to keep? All history means simply deleting the repository.

can you give more info about your repo like folder tree and content of .gitignore?

Maybe I didn't explain what I wanted to do correctly.
On my GIT server I have huge sized repo that only has master branch. When I examine my git server from my browser, I see lots of commits in the history of my master branch. I want to delete only the commits that appear in history from history without making any changes to the files in the branch. I want the result of the transaction to appear as if no commit was made to the master branch.

I think what you want is squashing all the commits into a single one. That way the content of the repo is preserved, but the history is not. Then force push to the server.

@KrzysiekKarbowiak no need to squash, create a new orphan branch and force-push. This will keep the latest commit

@Trax so you want to keep only the latest commit, but remove all commits before the latest? Remove everything but one?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102849/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+all+history

Deleting the .git folder may cause problems in your git repository. If you want to delete all your commit history but keep the code in its current state, it is very safe to do it as in the following:
Checkout/create orphan branch (this branch won't show in git branch command):
git checkout --orphan latest_branch
Add all the files to the newly created branch:
git add -A
Commit the changes:
git commit -am "commit message"
Delete main (default) branch (this step is permanent):
git branch -D main
Rename the current branch to main:
git branch -m main
Finally, all changes are completed on your local repository, and force update your remote repository:
git push -f origin main
PS: This will not keep your old commit history around. Now you should only see your new commit in the history of your git repository.
