# Is it possible to git --fixup on master

Tags: git

I'm looking for a way of merging all commit on master to one single commit and eventually rewrite a new commit to start from a fresh start.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your existing repository configuration you could do the following:

- `git checkout master`
- `git branch backup`: Optionally create a backup branch in case you want to keep your history.
- `git reset --soft $SHA_OF_INIT_COMMIT`: This will update what `HEAD` is pointing to but leave your index and working directory in their current state.
- `git commit --amend`: Change your initial commit to point to the current state of your repo.
- `git push --force`: Force push to `origin/master` to update the remote repository (if there is any).

I have just tried this and it worked like a charm. Credit for this goes to [Kevin M Granger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26144197/6551760). After this you might also want to run `git gc` on the local and remote repository  (again, if there is any). `git gc` runs a number of housekeeping tasks within the current repository, such as compressing file revisions (to reduce disk space and increase performance) and removing unreachable objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could delete your .git folder and just use the current source as the "initial commit" in a new Git repo.

Comment: I need to keep this repo sadly.

Comment: As I understand it, you're talking about completely changing the history of _master_. How is that "keeping this repo"?

Comment: Well keeping the name of the repo, but maybe should i delete the .git, the repo and redo one.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Use following Commands and Steps: 

    1) git rebase -i HEAD~2 origin/master    #2 is no of commits you want to fix

    Following window will open up
    pick 03d633e refactor
    pick d51b770 Updating Username comment

    # Rebase 2868146..d51b770 onto 2868146 (2 commands)
    #
    # Commands:
    # p, pick = use commit
    # r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
    # e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
    # s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
    # f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
    # x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
    # d, drop = remove commit
    #
    # These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
    #
    # If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
    #
    # However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
    #
    # Note that empty commits are commented out
    "~/WebstormProjects/Working/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo" 21L, 700C

2) To fixup : change pick to "fixup" or "f" and Save file .

     pick 03d633e refactor
     fixup  d51b770 Updating Username comment

3) Verify same using command:
     git log --oneline

4)force push changes :(Be Careful)
     git push origin HEAD:master --force
```