# Merging two git repositories to obtain linear history

Tags: git, merge

I have two git repositories and a lot of untracked changes between them:

```
   ftp -->            C-- (untracked changes) --D
                     /                           \
   git        A--B--C <-- old/master              \
                                                   \
                                                    \
                                  new/master -->     D--E--F
```

How can I merge old repository into new repository to have a linear history like

```
A--B--C--D--E--F
```

**EDIT:**

inspired by [How can I combine Git repositories into a linear history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780956/how-can-i-combine-git-repositories-into-a-linear-history)

I've done:

```
git clone url://new new
cd new/
git remote add old url://old
git fetch old
git reset --hard origin/master
git filter-branch --parent-filter 'sed "s_^\$_-p old/master_"' HEAD
git push origin master
```

Only problem is that every commit from new/master was doubled (due to change of parent I think) so I've now (M is merge commit)

```
         D---E---F--         
                    \
A--B--C--D'--E'--F'--M
```

How can I easily remove unnecessary commits (D - F and maybe M)?

Comment: Why not just pull from git repository where you are on F to that where you are on C?

Comment: So the "commits" C and D on ftp aren't really commits in Git except where they appear under old/master and new/master? And how was new/master created? `git init` in a copy of what was in ftp?

Comment: @andyg0808 Yes, "new" is created by running git init into fresh copy of ftp content. An yes, ftp is not a git branch, it's an old plain ftp.

Answer (score 6):

### Fixing the results of `git filter-branch`

If you have a repository that looks like this:

```
         D---E---F--
                    \
A--B--C--D'--E'--F'--M <-master
```

and you want the result to look like this:

```
A--B--C--D'--E'--F' <-master
```

then you can simply force `master` to point to `F'`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <sha1-of-F'>
```

This will cause commits `D`, `E`, `F`, and `M` to become unreachable, effectively deleting them (they will be garbage collected after a while).

### Starting over from scratch

Assuming you have two repositories that look like this:

- old:  `A--B--C <-master`
- new:  `D--E--F <-master`

and you want the result to be:

- combined:  `A--B--C--D'--E'--F' <- master`

then you can perform the following steps:

1. Initialize the `combined` repository:

   ```
   git init combined
   cd combined
   git remote add old url:/to/old
   git remote add new url:/to/new
   git remote update
   ```

   At this point your `combined` repository looks like:

   ```
   A--B--C <-old/master

   D--E--F <-new/master
   ```

   Note that the two branches aren't connected in any way.
2. Set your `master` branch to point to `C`:

   ```
   git reset --hard old/master
   ```

   Now your repository looks like this:

   ```
         old/master
         |
         v
   A--B--C <-master

   D--E--F <-new/master
   ```
3. Find the sha1 of `D`:

   ```
   d=$(git rev-list --reverse new/master | head -n 1)
   ```
4. Import `D` into your working directory and index by reading the contents of the commit

   ```
   git read-tree -u --reset $d
   ```
5. commit the contents of `D` using the same commit message, author, date, etc. as the original `D` commit:

   ```
   git commit -C $d
   ```

   Now your repository looks like this:

   ```
         old/master
         |
         v
   A--B--C--D' <-master

   D--E--F <-new/master
   ```
6. cherry-pick the rest of the commits:

   ```
   git cherry-pick $d..new/master
   ```

   Now your repository looks like this:

   ```
         old/master
         |
         v
   A--B--C--D'--E'--F' <-master

   D--E--F <-new/master
   ```
7. Clean up:

   ```
   git remote rm old
   git remote rm new
   ```

   Now your repository looks like this:

   ```
   A--B--C--D'--E'--F' <-master
   ```

Comment: Wow! That is one advanced and excellent answer. It worked much better then the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270041/add-history-to-git-repository-or-merge-git-repositories (which might be a duplicate)

Comment: Awesome. One minor thing: the cherry pick changes the creator of the commit, so e.g on GitHub it then shows `Original creator committed with YOU`

Comment: Probably `d=$(git rev-list new/master | tail -n 1)` is easier than first reversing and taking the first sha.

Answer (score 4):

Just check out your branch and run:

```
  git reset --hard **SHA-OF-F'**
```

That will remove `M` and `D`-`F` from your branch.

Answer (score 1):

If `ftp` is not a proper branch and just a copy paste job,
[this can work](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/815f4c1/scripts/jekyll-publish.sh#L36-L40)
for you

```
cd git
git rm -r .
cp -r ../ftp/. .
git add
git commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure what is the exact problem. But what I'd do is to remove one branch that contains the copy. Those commits aren't needed and will probably disappear with the branch being deleted. If they are doubled in the same tree, you can always use `git rebase` at your own risk.

doing something like

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

Will open an editor with things you can do. If you delete a line with a commit, it will delete it from the tree, you can squash commit together etc. If you save an empty file, it will not do anything.

That said, keep in mind that after doing such rebase, the master branch won't be fast forward and you'll have to override the master branch on the server. By forcing a push. In other word, make sure the rebase got right and that after pushing the new branch, everybody will get synced on this branch. If someone had a master and try to push and it fails it might make things worse.

Git rebase is just like replaying the commit history. Deleting a commit is more like skipping a change. If you skip a commit that is doubled then it won't have any effect. But each commit will have a different shasum and it also means that the branch will diverge from the original master.

In any case, before doing anything save the sha1 of the master and then if something goes wrong you can always checkout the master to the commit as long as there is no garbage collect.

Deleting the other branch would be the smartest idea and having every branch coming from this master will prevent doubles. Rebasing should be avoided unless you really have to.