# How to use git add the history after a repository has been created

Tags: git, github

A git repository was taken from a local system (localhub) and created on the project wide system (companyhub). However, the history was lost because the various files were committed at one time.

That is, the repository git@companyhub:projects/myproject.git was created without the history.

The `git log` on companyhub now reads

> Adding project processing to company git hub

with the date on which this was done.

Is there a way in which I can take the history which still exists on localhub and put it in to the repository which has been created on company hub.

I want to have git@companyhub:projects/myproject.git show the same log history as git@localhub:projects/localproject.git

Note that the files do not change. it is the history shown by `git log` that is to be fixed.

Would going into the clone created by localhub and issuing

```
git push git@companyhub:projects/myproject.git
```

work. I am reluctant to try it without first getting confirmation from someone who knows better.

Comment: Would it be easier to add the new repository as a remote and simply push the code to the new server?

Comment: @osowskit Yes, however, the point is that the original error was already done. I updated the question. Is that clearer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I combine Git repositories into a linear history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780956/how-can-i-combine-git-repositories-into-a-linear-history)

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to `pull` your old repository from the newer one. That way, you keep all the existing commit history

Comment: When I issued a pull in the directory created by the clone of the old one, the files are pulled from the new one,  the history (git log) does not change. What I want is to be able to update the history as shown by git log