# Git: How to find commits done from root?

Tags: git, github, root, commit

History in GitHub website doesn't show commits done from root.

Is there a way to find commits done from root?

Thanks!

Comment: And by "done from root", you mean as in `sudo git commit`? Or what is "root" in this context?

Comment: Note that in the context of Git, "root" usually refers to "root commit", i.e. a commit without parent, typically the first one done on a project.

Comment: Find the root (parentless) commits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006775/how-to-reference-the-initial-commit

Answer (score 2):

If `root` is the author of the commits you can use the `--author` flag:

```
git log --author root
```

Answer (score 0):

If by *root* you mean a branch named root, then you can go into the command line and type in:

```
git log | grep -B 2 'root'
```

This will return all of the commits done by *root*, and the commit hash.