# Squashing history from a range: from the initial commit to another

Tags: git, github, merge

I am trying to find out how to squash commits in Git from a range of commits. My specific situation is that I forked a repository and added several commits of work on top of it; however I'd like to squash all of the forked repo's commits to a single commit to keep the history clean.

#### Example

```
7e8d7f7 - (HEAD) My commit
809fc8b - My commit
e04692c - Forked repo's commit          \
2674323 - Forked repo's commit           > Turn these into a single commit
4e79731 - Forked repo's initial commit  /
```

#### Here's something I've tried

1. Get the SHA for the initial commit via `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD` for the ***lower bound*** of the range I want to squash ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006775/how-to-reference-the-initial-commit))
2. Detach the HEAD to the ***upper bound*** of the range via `git checkout <upper bound commit>`
3. Soft reset to the lower bound and commit (alternative to `git rebase -i`): `git reset --soft <lower bound commit> && git commit` ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/350951))
4. Merge into `master`: `git merge --no-ff master`

I end up getting tons of merge conflicts this way. I feel that what I'm trying to achieve is possible with the commands I've encountered, but I'm at a loss at how to string them together to make it work.

Comment: This sounds like a particularly unwise solution. Did you try just copy-and-pasting the code and creating a new git repository there? Because it has the same effect.

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this? It is absolutely clear that you would get merge conflicts. If you change previous commits, then you are creating a completely new repository. All the answers provided will give you merge conflicts. What is your inherent motivation to want "to keep the history clean"?

Comment: @Unapiedra I forked a boilerplate project and made some work on top of it, but instead of deleting the `.git` folder before starting my work, I kept committing to the forked repo. Yes, I understand everyone's concerns here; please do not attempt this unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I would avoid doing this.

Git history is a beautiful thing and future users of you repo might want to know the exact point where you forked.

Or you may want to pull additional commits from the remote at a later time, and that will probably be easier if you don't go out of your way to mess up the shared history.

That said, this should work for you:

```sh
git checkout e04692c -b squashing_branch

git reset --soft $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)
git commit --amend -m "Forked repo as one big commit"

git cherry-pick e04692c..master
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. For the final step, how do I make `squashing_branch` into master?

Comment: This answer does the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2862606/350951 Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not do this.
2. You can just create a new repository. Because that is exactly the same as squashing all the commits before you are starting work.

    `# Get the original git repository somehow
    $ git clone URL
    # Delete the old repo
    $ cd your-repo; rm -rf .git/
    $ git init  # create new repo.
    $ git add -a
    $ git commit -m 'Forked repo from X and squashed all commits'
    # Now start working.
    # Again, I think this whole undertaking is misguided.`
3. You create a new commit with no parent as the "squashed" commit. 
   Let's assume that the real history is on a branch called "long_history".

   ```
   git checkout master  # assuming on master is the complete history.
   # Create a new branch without any history. A new root so to speak.
   git checkout --orphan squashed_master 
   # All the files from the original 'master' will be already added
   # to the index. 
   git commit -m 'Squashed all of the previous history as cloned from X'.
   # Delete the master branch and create it again
   git branch -D master
   git branch master
   git push --force -u origin master  # Assuming that 'origin' is the remote of your fork and not the original repository. Change accordingly...
   ```
4. I still think that you should not do this.

Final note: I thought that subtree might be an option. I tried to use `git subtree` but that did not work with `--prefix=.`.