# How to refer to beginning of repository in Git

Tags: git

If `HEAD` points to the latest tip of the repository, how could I get reference to the very beginning of a repository in a similar fashion?

Comment: There's nothing built in - indeed, there can be more than one "orphan" commit (a commit without parents) - just `git checkout --orphan` - and any could claim to be a "root"

Comment: Might be a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006775/how-to-reference-the-initial-commit

Comment: For some purposes you can use the all-zeros hash to refer to *before* the first commit ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such a thing. You can have multiple *unrelated* branches each one with their own starting revision (actually, a single branch can have multiple starting revisions... if there was a merge of unrelated histories, for example).

As a side note, `HEAD`, unlike svn, is not the tip of the repo. `HEAD` is wherever you are standing, not necessarily the last revision of a branch... and what does all of that mean?

```
git checkout main~5
```

So, you are 5 revisions behind `main`... well, that's where `HEAD` is.

Answer (score 2):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006775/how-to-reference-the-initial-commit) might help.

In short, `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD` worked for me.

Comment: This is very good, actually.... but it's not bullet-proof.  There are a number of gotchas: different branches could have different starting points (something perfectly possible with git)... or a branch could have more than one starting point. Upvoted, just in case.