# Get first commit if no tag is existing

Tags: git, shell

To get the commit of the latest tag, I'm doing

```
$(git rev-parse $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0))
```

But if there is no tag at all, it will throw the error `fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything`.
So in case, there is no tag at all, I would like to get the first commit at all. How do I have to do it?

```
$(git rev-parse $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 || <?-- get the very first commit -->))
```

Comment: Are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006775/how-to-reference-the-initial-commit ?

Comment: I would preemptively tag the first commit; that tag would either be ignored (if there is already a later tag) or prevent `git rev-parse` failing.

Comment: @chepner Oh, that's a good point. Easy, but didn't see this option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the first commit in the repository is to use [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list) and ask for the list of commits in [*reverse*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---reverse) [*topological*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---topo-order) order:

```sh
git rev-list --topo-order --reverse --all | head -1
```

This will return the SHA-1 hash of the first commit in the entire history graph, regardless of when it was created.

Comment: Or at least, *a* first commit—there could be more than one first commit...